# Bootstrap Backdrop scrolling on jquery opened modals

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a 2 modals, the first modal is triggered to get the user email. After the user have validated the email address and clicked on continue it will trigger the 2nd modal which is a longer modal that is scrollable. Now, this modal is triggered programmatically from the code.

```
$('#modalEmailSignup').modal('hide');

$('#modalSignupForm').modal('show');
```

This is my code. It is working properly. But the problem is that the scrollable area for the 2nd modal is the backdrop. I am not sure if I am triggering the modal correctly. I tried closing all the modals before opening a new with this code.

```
$('.modal .close).trigger('click');
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I tried looking on the flow of opening the other scrollable modals and it seems that it is adding 'modal-open' class on the body. I tried adding it when I open the modal but still not working. I am running out of ideas to try to solve this issue. Have anyone encountered this issue? Please let me know your insights. Thanks :)

BTW: I am using angular here, it will work if I add (data-target='#targetModal' ,data-dismiss='modal') but I added a ng-click attribute to execute a validation function first before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2132/

```js
$('button[btnClass="close"]').click(function(){
 $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
 $('#myModal2').modal({show: true});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Modal Example</h3>

  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div>
    <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" btnClass="close" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary save">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Modal 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
```

In the solution,
I have two modals. **First modal** will launch on **clicking** the **launch** **button**.

When you **click close** button in the **first** **modal**, **second modal** will show up.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using this but the the modal is still unscrollable for long modals

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2133/ Updated the code, added a bunch of breaks to make the modal longer

Comment: i had the showing of modals working. My problem was the scroll bar for longer modals

Comment: Nope, the modal should be scrollable and the backdrop should be static.

Comment: I have added data-backdrop='static' on my modal class as well but still not work.

Comment: Oh I think you meant that the scroll bar will be for the body. Yes the scroll bar should be on the body and it will scroll the modal itself not the whole page

Comment: Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2134/ .. I guess this is what you are looking for..... **Don't add content in the modal-header section**....

Comment: Here is a sample of the scrolling I want to achieve https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FI52ZNW37BD5

Comment: @banri16... Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/6x4t0n3r/1/

Comment: Thanks @Shiladitya for your help. The code you gave me is working. I also did some workaround for that. `$('signup-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          //   if($scope.openSignUpModal){
          //     $('#modalSignupForm').modal({show: true});
          //     $scope.openSignUpModal  = false;
          //   }
          // });` I added a bind whenever the modal is closed. I also added a parameter for checking if I needed to open a modal. This helped me prevent to the scrolling of contents behind the modal. Thanks again for your help :)